# Measuring R-Squared by category

Tags: regression, python, scikit-learn

It makes sense to look at metrics like recall/precision by category when performing classification. sklearn has [classification_report](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html)  for this purpose. But what if I want to look at error by category in the context of a regression problem? Are there best practices for this?

For example if I want to predict a target variable `employee_salary` using three predictor variables. Two integer variables `years_of_school` and `years_on_the_job` and one categorical variable `industry` which is one-hot encoded.

`employee_salary` ~ `years_of_school` + `years_on_the_job` + `industry_gov` + `industry_edu` + `industry_fin` ...

My goal is to figure out the R2 by industry to see if there are specific industries that are more/less predictable and may warrant more attention. How and when in the modeling process do I do this?

Comment: I would look at the Sum of Squares from an ANOVA rather.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could separate both the data and regression results by category, then for each category calculate R-squared (R2) as "R2 = 1.0 - (residual_error_variance / dependent_data_variance)". Using numpy's var() function makes this easy, as in "R2 = 1.0 - (numpy.var(error) / numpy.var(dep_data))".